# Javascript function that works with or without CSS3

Tags: javascript, css

How would you implement a Javascript function that fades out a DOM element, using CSS3 if available (but is still functional when CSS3 isn't available)?

Comment: I would use a library. I also suggest reformulating the question so as not to sound subjective.

Comment: I would just toggle a class to use CSS3 and let it degrade gracefully on old browsers. People that don't see a transition are most likely to not care. Better browsers offer a better experience, and that's fine. Just my 2c

Comment: The only browsers not supporting CSS Transitions are IE8 and IE9. Notice how those are outdated versions. I would not worry about those as this (fading) is a presentational enhancement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd use something like [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/) to detect if css3 transitions are available or not:

```
if(!Modernizr.csstransitions) {
    // css3 isn't available
    // maybe dealing with it in jQuery ?? or plain js
}
```

Comment: If you take the effort to write code for a fallback, why not use the fallback for all scenarios and save yourself the hassle of doing it twice?

Comment: @Jonathan performance

Comment: Sorry I don't see how adding libraries for browser function testing reduces overhead.

Comment: @Jonathan if available, technology is the way to go, as old patterns are not optimized to use recent hardware / software features, just think about `Canvas`, it was a real pain for the user to draw a single line without that.. but it worked

Comment: @Jonathan adding a library might not reduce overhead, but offloading transitions to CSS surely does.